# d3 doughpie/bubble chart combo with animation tweening

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created this chart in static form - to exactly how it needs to be -- but I've lost animation and morphing along the way ---

```
   1. -- how to animate the arcs
   2. -- how to animate the bubbles
   3. -- adding back the randomise button to test with 2 dummy data sets.
```

I need the arcs to tween like they did before -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1452/

[image]

Latest fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1506/

---

this is the old pie animations and worked very well

```
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
                var slice = doughpie.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
                  .data(pie(data), key);

                slice.enter()
                  .insert("path")
                  .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(d.data.label);
                  })
                  .style("transform", function(d, i){
                    //return "translate(0, 0)";
                  })
                  .attr("class", "slice");

                slice
                  .transition().duration(1000)
                  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                      return arc(interpolate(t));
                    };
                  })

                slice.exit()
                  .remove();
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
```

//this is the current pie arcs - but when I try and animate the pie in the same manner - it fails.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
  });

arc
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);
```

Comment: any suggestions -- even we start re-animating the pie chart that will be a start -- why is this code not interchangable? why does one have append and the other insert

Comment: I really need help with this - I've tried for days to get these arcs to re-tween - is it a scope thing - where the g elements are old/non-existent?